# QuillJs is slow with large documents

Tags: quill

When creating large documents (more than 100,000 words) the editor becomes increasingly laggy to the point of being frustrating to use.

Is there a way to control how much of the document is rendered to the DOM while still allowing the user to edit the entire document?

It appears that Quill is rendering all of the editor content nodes to the DOM regardless of whether the nodes are visible to the user or not. As a comparison, a similar slowness can be felt when working with a large amount of text in a basic html textbox element.

[All nodes rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb98H.png)

I have come across other projects that handle this issue by keeping unseen content out of the DOM. Here are two examples:

The [Ace editor](http://%20https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) handles this by rendering only the currently visible content in the DOM.

And [Clusterize.js](https://github.com/NeXTs/Clusterize.js) handles row data similarly.

I have been reading the Quill documentation, but have not found a solution yet.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide a example reproducing your issue. I've tried this fiddle and cannot see any slowness http://jsfiddle.net/6xmLz9q2/

Comment: @KamilNiski Thank you for posting your fiddle. When I use it, it demonstrates the same issue I am explaining.

If you do the following, you should see it (hopefully):

1. Run your fiddle
2. Click on the text entry are
3. Mash a bunch of keys as quickly as you can for a few seconds
4. Watch as the screen tries to catch up after you have finished typing

If you're not entering text quickly, the delay isn't as noticeable.

Please let me know if you can see it using the steps above to reproduce.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't experience the slow performance. Although I've seen some reports in the web about it. Currently quill doesn't have any means to lazy render the contents.

Comment: @KamilNiski Thanks for the info. I appreciate you testing as well. I am getting the slow behavior across multiple browsers on multiple systems. It does not look like quill will fulfill the requirements of this project at this time due to the way it treats content in the DOM.